# Animate Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate an object using JQuery so that when you use the arrowkeys it will move.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(document).keydown(function(key) {
    switch(parseInt(key.which,10)) {
        case 65:
            $('img').animate({left: "-=10px"},500);
            break;
        case 83:
        $('img').animate({top:"+=10px"},500);
            break;
        case 87:
        $('img').animate({up:"-=10px"},500);    
            break;
        case 68:
        $('img').animate({right:"-=10px"},500);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
});
```

This is my code that I have for the image and it is not working. Does anything stick out to you immediately that looks wrong?

Answer (score 2):

key.which is already an integer, no need to parse it, and the numbers are wrong, and so are the CSS properties, there's no such thing as `up`, and CSS properties like top and left has no effect on static elements, so you'll have to add a position :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).keydown(function (key) {
        switch (key.which) {
            case 37:
                $('img').animate({
                    left: "-=10px"
                }, 500);
                break;
            case 40:
                $('img').animate({
                    top: "+=10px"
                }, 500);
                break;
            case 39:
                $('img').animate({
                    left: "+=10px"
                }, 500);
                break;
            case 38:
                $('img').animate({
                    top: "-=10px"
                }, 500);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zBVN6/)